# Почему размер шрифта на Mac и Windows отличается

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, шрифты, ос

Сайт сделан на бутсрапе и суть в том, что на винде размер шрифта пунктов меню 20, а на маке 22 или больше. Я не понимаю, откуда эта разница? Что с ней делать?

Comment: Проверьте масштабы в браузерах и покажите скриншоты, чтобы было понятнее о каких пунктах речь

Answer (score 2):

Каждый браузер имеет свои стандартные настройки стилей, например если значения для элемента `<p>` не заданы, то:

```
// iOS Safari 

line-height: 1.4

// Chrome

line-height: 1
```

Что бы обезопасить себя, и получить результат когда Ваш дизайн отображаться во всех браузерах одинаково задавайте основные значения explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали выше, в каждом браузере все параметры по-умолчанию свои. Можно использовать [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), подключая его самым первым, он "сбрасывает" все параметры. Как итог во всех браузерах все размеры отображаются одинаково.